# BrightCove Video Player not working on Android

Tags: brightcove

java.lang.RuntimeException: A Component requires the 'com.brightcove.player.event.Emits' annotation.  If you wish to not listen or emit, create the corresponding annotation with an empty events list.

Has any one else face the same issue??

any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you do not have the annotation

```
@Emits(events = {})
```

before your class declaration.  If you show us the relevant fragment it might be obvious to someone what the problem is.  A component that emits no events and listens for no events would look like,

```
/**
 * Provides a Component object that is not very useful.
 */
@Emits(events = {})
@ListensFor(events = {})
public class NotVeryUsefulComponent extends AbstractComponent {
}
```

Comment: Yes i tried that also. But the strange issue here is that when i run unsigned build it works, as soon as i signed it with pro-guard, it gives this exception.

Answer (score 2):

Please update the proguard with the following lines

```
-keep public class com.brightcove.player.** { public *;}
-keepclassmembers public class com.brightcove.player.** { public *;}
-keepclasseswithmembers public class com.brightcove.player.** { public *;}
-keep class com.google.android.exoplayer.** { *;}
```

If you are not using the exoplayer, omit the last line

Comment: I used it and it generated the signed apk successfully, but the problem is it shows ANR at runtime that says: **Error inflating class com.brightcove.player.view.BrightcoveExoPlayerVideoView**

Comment: That seems to be something different. Are you extending the class properly?

Answer (score 0):

Your proguard configuration is stripping out the annotations.  As an example, please see the proguard-project.txt in our samples repo:

https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/android-player-samples/blob/master/proguard-project.txt